# Does it make sense to talk about complex matrices over the field of real numbers, R?

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

I don't see an issue with considering a vector space of complex matrices over R -- addition of matrices makes sense, but scalar multiplication will be done with real numbers.

But I wanted to ask, just in case I may have it wrong.

Thanks,

Edit: As far as I know, the entries being complex does *not* make it a vector space over C - it is the numbers that we are using to scale the matrices that determine the ground field.  (But like I said, I *may* have it wrong...)

Comment: There is no problem: any complex vector space can be considered a real vector space by *restriction of scalars*.

Comment: Given a vector space $V$ and a field $F$, what we need to check before assuring that it is a vector space is to check all vector space axioms including those operations, then done. So you can check the axioms now, then you can say it makes sense to say so.

Comment: Ahh, got it - thanks @Bernard.

Comment: Yes, what a nice, simple explanation @Salomo.  Thanks so much :-)

Comment: Indeed, such a vector space would be isomorphic to $M \times M$ where $M$ is a matrix space over the reals.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Archaick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector space is actually a $4$-uple $(V, \Bbb F, +, \cdot)$, where $V$ is a set, $\Bbb F$ is the underlying field, and $+$ and $\cdot$ are operations $+: V\times V \to V$, $\cdot : \Bbb F \times V \to V $ satisfying some conditions. We abuse notation and call $(V,\Bbb F, +, \cdot)$ only $V$, the rest being understood from context.

If you have a complex vector space, that is, $(V, \Bbb C, +,\cdot)$, then $(V, \Bbb R, +, \cdot\big|_{\Bbb R \times V})$ is a real vector space. Note that $V$ and $+$ are the same in both cases. That's all there is to it.

Comment: got it - thanks, @IvoTerek :-)